# Neo4j : How to use DELETE clause for the UNION returned result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how can I execute the DELETE clause in below statement?

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'ce5e59de-af34-4dba-a134-8ff1de3696b6'})-[r:WRITE*..2]-(p) 
RETURN u,r,p 
UNION MATCH (u:User {userId:'ce5e59de-af34-4dba-a134-8ff1de3696b6'})-[r:COMMENT]-(p) 
RETURN u,r,p
```

Comment: There has been a long-standing request for some kind of UNION WITH functionality to allow for post-UNION processing, but until that's added to neo4j, we have to rely on workarounds without UNION.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a `DELETE` to the query you've written, but you can however write it differently to delete each step independently:

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'ce5e59de-af34-4dba-a134-8ff1de3696b6'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:WRITE*..2]-(p)
DETACH DELETE p
WITH DISTINCT u
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:COMMENT]-(p)
DETACH DELETE u, p
```